# AngularJS how to build reusable datatable UI component

Tags: angularjs, node.js, datatable, pagination

I am working on building a reusable datatable with pagination and search.

I have a working controller that creates the datatable, pagination and search and sets variables using 'this' (rather than $scope). This works properly. However, it is using hard-coded data for the time being.

Questions:

1 How do I pass in the data dynamically to the TablePaginationController when it is called (rather than the hard-coded list "items").

2 How do I make the TablePaginationController reusable with the ability to pass in different data sets (with the same structure).

3 I think perhaps a Service would be a good approach here, but I have no idea where to start with that... do I create the pagination controller as a service and inject that into the page controllers?

TablePaginationController creates the datatable and performs all of the pagination and searching.

HistoryPageController sends a GET request to grab data from the API and returns the response in JSON. There will be other controllers such as DetailsPageController that will need to also do that and pass in a different set of data.

```
app.controller('TablePaginationController', function($http, $filter, $location) {

    const vm = this;
    // init
    vm.sortingOrder = 'name';
    vm.reverse = false;
    vm.filteredItems = [];
    vm.groupedItems = [];
    vm.itemsPerPage = 10;
    vm.pagedItems = [];
    vm.currentPage = 0;
    vm.items = [
        {"id":"1","name":"name 1","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 1","field4":"field4 1","field5 ":"field5 1"},
        {"id":"2","name":"name 2","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 2","field4":"field4 2","field5 ":"field5 2"},
        {"id":"3","name":"name 3","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 3","field4":"field4 3","field5 ":"field5 3"},
        {"id":"4","name":"name 4","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 4","field4":"field4 4","field5 ":"field5 4"},
        {"id":"5","name":"name 5","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 5","field4":"field4 5","field5 ":"field5 5"},
        {"id":"6","name":"name 6","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 6","field4":"field4 6","field5 ":"field5 6"},
        {"id":"7","name":"name 7","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 7","field4":"field4 7","field5 ":"field5 7"},
        {"id":"8","name":"name 8","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 8","field4":"field4 8","field5 ":"field5 8"},
        {"id":"9","name":"name 9","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 9","field4":"field4 9","field5 ":"field5 9"},
        {"id":"10","name":"name 10","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 10","field4":"field4 10","field5 ":"field5 10"},
        {"id":"11","name":"name 11","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 11","field4":"field4 11","field5 ":"field5 11"},
        {"id":"12","name":"name 12","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 12","field4":"field4 12","field5 ":"field5 12"},
        {"id":"13","name":"name 13","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 13","field4":"field4 13","field5 ":"field5 13"},
        {"id":"14","name":"name 14","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 14","field4":"field4 14","field5 ":"field5 14"},
        {"id":"15","name":"name 15","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 15","field4":"field4 15","field5 ":"field5 15"},
        {"id":"16","name":"name 16","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 16","field4":"field4 16","field5 ":"field5 16"},
        {"id":"17","name":"name 17","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 17","field4":"field4 17","field5 ":"field5 17"},
        {"id":"18","name":"name 18","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 18","field4":"field4 18","field5 ":"field5 18"},
        {"id":"19","name":"name 19","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 19","field4":"field4 19","field5 ":"field5 19"},
        {"id":"20","name":"name 20","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 20","field4":"field4 20","field5 ":"field5 20"}
    ];

    var searchMatch = function (haystack, needle) {
        if (!needle) {
            return true;
        }
        return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    };

    // init the filtered items
    vm.search = function () {
        vm.filteredItems = $filter('filter')(vm.items, function (item) {
            for(var attr in item) {
                if (searchMatch(item[attr], vm.query))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
        // take care of the sorting order
        if (vm.sortingOrder !== '') {
            vm.filteredItems = $filter('orderBy')(vm.filteredItems, vm.sortingOrder, vm.reverse);
        }
        vm.currentPage = 0;
        // now group by pages
        vm.groupToPages();
    };

    // calculate page in place
    vm.groupToPages = function () {
        vm.pagedItems = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < vm.filteredItems.length; i++) {
            if (i % vm.itemsPerPage === 0) {
                vm.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / vm.itemsPerPage)] = [ vm.filteredItems[i] ];
            } else {
                vm.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / vm.itemsPerPage)].push(vm.filteredItems[i]);
            }
        }
    };

    vm.range = function (start, end) {
        var ret = [];
        if (!end) {
            end = start;
            start = 0;
        }
        for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
            ret.push(i);
        }
        return ret;
    };

    vm.prevPage = function () {
        if (vm.currentPage > 0) {
            vm.currentPage--;
        }
    };

    vm.nextPage = function () {
        if (vm.currentPage < vm.pagedItems.length - 1) {
            vm.currentPage++;
        }
    };

    vm.setPage = function (pg) {
        vm.currentPage = pg;
    };

    // functions have been describe process the data for display
    vm.search();

    // change sorting order
    vm.sort_by = function(newSortingOrder) {
        if (vm.sortingOrder == newSortingOrder)
            vm.reverse = !vm.reverse;
        alert(newSortingOrder);
        vm.sortingOrder = newSortingOrder;

        // icon setup
        $('th i').each(function(){
            // icon reset
            $(this).removeClass().addClass('icon-sort');
        });
        if (vm.reverse)
            $('th.'+newSortingOrder+' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-up');
        else
            $('th.'+newSortingOrder+' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-down');
    };
});

app.controller('HistoryPageController', function($http) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.title = 'Transfer Request History';

  /*Get Transfer Request History*/
  $http({
      url: `/transfer_request/history/json`,
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(function (response){
    vm.treq = response.data;
    console.log('HistoryPageController API call worked', response);
   },function (error){
    console.log('HistoryPageController API error: ', error);
   });

});
```

Comment: Well, since you want to create a reusable component, the first thing would be to create a real `component` or `directive` instead of using `ngController`. Also, consider having a more general component and if the requirements for a feature get too restrictive you can inherit from that component and add specific behavior.

Comment: Sure, the AngularJS [documentation on components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) has the kind of information you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I ended up creating a factory service to perform all of the logic for the datatable, pagination and search. Next I injected the new service into multiple controllers for re-usability.